# looping over a data.frame columns in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, lapply

In my function `foo` below, I was wondering how I could loop over `what`?

```
foo <- function(data, what){
formula <- as.formula(paste('~', what))
dum <- data.frame(model.matrix(formula, data = data))[-1L] 
cbind(data, dum)
} 

dat <- data.frame(number = -3:2, gender = rep(c("M","F"), 3), region = rep(LETTERS[1:2],3))
```

**I tried the following without success:**

```
what = c('gender', "region")

dat[what] <- lapply(what, function(i) foo(dat, what = i))
dat
```

Comment: What is your expected output, If you just need the 'dum' output, then don't `cbind` at the last step

Comment: In that case just do `dum <- model.matrix(formula, data = data)[,-1] ; dum}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need to create new columns

```
foo <- function(data, what){
    formula <- as.formula(paste('~', what))
    data.frame(model.matrix(formula, data = data))[-1]
   }

what = c('gender', "region")

cbind(dat, do.call(cbind, lapply(what, foo, data = dat)))
#   number gender region genderM regionB
#1     -3      M      A       1       0
#2     -2      F      B       0       1
#3     -1      M      A       1       0
#4      0      F      B       0       1
#5      1      M      A       1       0
#6      2      F      B       0       1
```

---

In the OP's function, the output is the whole dataset (with the new column) from `cbind`.  This when run individually is fine as it adds a new column along with the whole dataset.  But, when we do this multiple times, the initial dataset is duplicated.  Instead, we just return the output of `model.matrix` column as a single column and `cbind` with the original dataset

Comment: @Reza Are you updating the 'what' columns or creating new columns with 'M' as suffix

Comment: @Reza it is just based on your function.  I just removed the `cbind`

Comment: @Reza I got that point, but in your post you are assinging to `what` i.e. `dat[what] <-`